# tf.all_variables() equivalent for states

Tags: tensorflow

`tf.all_variables()` gives all Graph variables. Is there an equivalent for all state-tensors?

Background: I want to debug my Graph's behaviour. So again and again I want to check into state-tensors given some input-feed. Usually you would define these when building the Graph and then

session.run(looking_for_this_tensor, input_feed)

to inspect them.

I would, however, much rather have something like this:

```
for v in tf.all_state_tensors_type_of_method():
    print (v.name, ': ', session.run(v, input_feed))
```

Is there something like that? Looked extensively but couldn't find it.

Comment: If you want to print the value of certain tensors in the graph, I would recommend using `graph.get_tensor_by_name('your_tensor_name')` where `graph=tf.get_default_graph()`. You can get the names of the wanted tensors in the **graph view** of Tensorboard.

Comment: Thx. Need to click my way manually through Tensorboard? No iteration in python possible to find the names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do that would be to run a loop on every operation in the graph, and for each operation print its output.

The code would look like that:

```py
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    for op in graph.get_operations():
        for tensor in op.outputs:
            print tensor.name, ':', sess.run(tensor, feed_dict=input_feed)
```

---

### Warning

Doing that with a big graph and with tensors with big shapes would result in a complete mess, as it will print **every** sub tensor used in the computations.
You will also need to refer to Tensorboard for the exact names of the tensors, and/or adopt a good naming convention (with `tf.name_scope()`for instance).

Comment: Excellent, thx. I would not even have to look them up in Tensorboard but could inspect them by simple search as in `if tensor.name.find("string") > -1` before the eval

Comment: Keep in mind that what you do is kind of *bad practice* but whatever :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm still new to this and currently just crash and burn a little - Get an idea of how things work. So being able to peek into the flow without much planning is nice. Later the code will need to be cleaner :)

Answer (score 1):

You could also add to a collection the tensors that you want to inspect.

```
t1 = ... variable / constant
t2 = ... variable / constant

tf.add_to_collection("inspect", t1)
tf.add_to_collection("inspect", t2)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(..., feed_dict={..})
for v in tf.get_collection("inspect):
    v.eval()
```